# Rails 4.0.0 console not starting in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

On my server I had console working fine last week. Now when I run

```
rails console RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get the following error.

```
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files  accordingly:

* development - set it to false
* test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
* production - set it to true
```

In my production.rb I have the following line:

```
config.eager_load = true
```

rails console in development env does run on my server

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The command to start the Rails console in production mode:

```
rails console production
```

Comment: That's a bull's eye shot! Nice!!